# Rearrange the position of Follow button on Lightning Page layout

Tags: case, page-layout, button, lightning-page, standardlayout

Quick question, can we move/rearrange position of standard Follow Button? I do know about Hide/Unhide, here i just want to move its position from start to middle or bottom. if its not possible, can i have any SF documentation for reference?

Thanks in Advance.

[image: Follow Button]

Comment: Hello , Do you want to hide the Follow button ?

Comment: no, i want to reorder. however i got my answer in your next comment. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement , this functionality is still under Idea Exchange [Ability to Reorder or Rearrange Standard Buttons on Layouts](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdn2AUAR/ability-to-reorder-or-rearrange-standard-buttons-on-layouts) , I would request you to upvote and follow this idea to get the regular updates .

However if you want to hide the Standard Follow Button , you can check this for your help [Hide or unhide the Follow record button on a Lightning Page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390149&type=1) .

Hope the above information helps !

Comment: Yes @subrat, Thanks. I wanted to know about the "Ability to Reorder or Rearrange".